# Getting chrome to open "text" files in a tab

Tags: google-chrome, download

When I look at code samples on the web that are linked to as a .c, .cpp, .h etc file, chrome will download it for me as a file.

Is there a way to get it to open the file (which is really just a text file with a different extension, and chrome does open text files in a tab window) in a tab window?

I would rather not have my downloads folder littered with all of these small code files.

I have looked in the chrome preferences, but have not found anything that relates to this.

Running the dev build of chrome, but I would take the option in any current build of the browser.

**EDIT:** Is there a way to change the way that chrome handles some mime types like `text/x-chdr` or others?

Comment: Can you even edit Google Chrome's file associations?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It generally uses my OSes file associations to open files with the correct extension...

Comment: You can manage file associations with Firefox's `Options > Applications` dialog. If Google Chrome had a comparable feature, you would have the choice to open the files in a new tab or another application directly. As far as I can tell, Google Chrome lacks such preferences. `:(`

Comment: Can you write an extension to do this?

Comment: Are you asking if I personally can, or if chrome supports it?

Comment: Does it happen with all source files from any site or just a specific site?

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it myself. Opening a local `CPP` file (i.e., `file:///….cpp`) *does* open as text, only remote ones try to download.

Comment: [\[1\]](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/mqbdHOu8hHM) [\[2\]](http://binfalse.de/2011/06/apache-displaying-instead-of-downloading/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a C program file in browser window?](http://superuser.com/questions/136982/how-to-open-a-c-program-file-in-browser-window)

Comment: In Opera, this would be under `Prefereces > Advanced > Downloads`, but I don't think there's anything comparable in Chrome. Are your OS file associations ignored if you set, say, `.cpp` files to be opened with Chrome?

Comment: aaamos, I am using chrome, so not sure what you mean. @Synetech, that answer has 1) a faulty premise (no viewer required, default works just fine) 2) my issue is not related to Gmail (nor was the OP's in that question) I an just want to change the storage location to somewhere else (i.e. not my normal downloads folder, but a temp directory / just RAM or something, like other web pages). In short, don't think its a dupe

Comment: Actually it is. The point is that Chrome handles some file-types differently.

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe pointing in a helpful direction: in Firefox this is possible via a browser extension called [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/). Maybe Chrome could be likewise extended.

Answer (score 22):

I did a bunch of tests and found that some types *always* trigger a download from remote location. For example, `.bat` files *always* try to download while the similar `.cmd` type opens as text. Likewise, `.cpp` files *always* trigger a download while my own `.inc` type which is an identical copy of the `.cpp` with the “cpp” changed to “inc” opens as text.

I haven’t checked the source, but I suspect it’s a built-in behavior. They must figure that if it’s a local file (`file:///…`), you already have it so it is assumed to be trusted, so open it. If however it is a remote file, don’t open it, instead download it so that any anti-virus software on the system can have a look to be safe.

Surprisingly there [do not seem to be any other complaints](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=text%20download%20view&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&cells=tiles) about this on the Chrome bug tracker. `o.O` I have submitted [a report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118204&thanks=118204&ts=1331749873), so we’ll have to see what they say.

Comment: Thanks. And also surprisingly only 10 users have upvoted (starred) it. +1 (me).

Comment: @ChrisJJ: That number is now up to 17, and I've added a comment with some thoughts about what the user interface should look like.

Comment: Thanks to Synetech for opening a ticket in the Chrome bug tracker, and helpfully providing the link.  I've added my vote and a supportive comment.  Have you?  :-)

Comment: Tnx for issue, voted up!

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118204&thanks=118204&ts=1331749873

It was closed automatically, I don't see how to reopen

Answer (score 3):

Great question.

I can be achieved via an extension:

- For Chrome, load [undisposition](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/undisposition?hl=en)
- If the file loading is ASCII then colour coding may be desirable, that can be done via 
  the [Syntaxtic](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Syntaxtic!?hl=en) extension
- btw, for Firefox load the [InlineDisposition](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inlinedisposition-reloaded) add-on

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [Syntaxtic! for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cgjalgdhmbpaacnnejmodfinclbdgaci?hl=en-US), worked for me. It opens source code in a new tab and then applies syntax highlighting.

Comment: Does not work for me. How do you use it?

Comment: I installed Syntaxtic!, but `CPP` files still open a *Save As* dialog instead of in a tab as plain-text.

Answer (score 0):

## Google Chrome

Now its possible to open source code directly from browser. I tested on version 61.0.3163.91 64 bits.

## Firefox

Here it isn't yet. To avoid this, do the following:

1. Right-click on .c or other source code file;
2. `Copy link` option
3. Press `CRTL-T` to open new tab;
4. Type "view-source:"
5. Paste the link copied before.

Done! Firefox will show the source code of the file, in this case, the file itself.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the same question and found the answer from Danny B. at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952514/how-to-force-open-links-in-chrome-not-download-them.

> To make certain file types OPEN on your computer, instead of Chrome
>   Downloading...
>
> You have to download the file type once, then right after that
>   download, look at the status bar at the bottom of the browser. Click
>   the arrow next to that file and choose "always open files of this
>   type". DONE.
>
> Now the file type will always OPEN using your default program.
>
> To reset this feature, go to Settings / Advance Settings and under the
>   "Download.." section, there's a button to reset 'all' Auto Downloads

Comment: I wanted this to open in a chrome tab, not the system text editor

Comment: This could work, if the default program is set to chrome. I have no environment to test it. Of course this affects also other situations where you might not want it