# How do I open a source code file in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download

Some files, like `txt` can be opened in Chrome. How do I open `py` files that are linked on the page, and prevent them from bringing up the download dialog box?

Like this, for example http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/scatter_demo2.py It is unnecessary to download the file. I just want to preview it in the browser.

Comment: I normally just drag and drop the file into the browser.  Of course that will just allow you to view it not edit it.

Comment: This actually has something to do with plaintext files being linked on the page. Local files are easy to preview, with Quick Look on the Mac, for example. I've updated the question.

Comment: I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/399538/getting-chrome-to-open-text-files-in-a-tab) previous question. It doesn't seem to have a solution though.